# Adjoint of Derivative Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working on this problem, and it seems like it shouldn't be too difficult, but I can't seem to piece it together.

Let $V$ be the space of 2-periodic (period of 2) functions $f$ with the inner product 
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_{1}^{2} f(t)g(t)\,dt $$ and let $T$ be the derivative operator.

I need to find $T^*.$ I tried using the definition of an adjoint map, but I wasn't able to figure out how exactly it follows.

Comment: Try partial integration to move the derivative operator from acting on f to g or vice versa.

Comment: @MathLogic Partial integration is integration by parts.

Answer (score 4):

$\langle f, D^{*}g \rangle = \langle Df, g\rangle  \iff \int_{0}^{2} f(x) (D^{*}g)(x) dx = \int_{0}^{2} (Df)(x) g(x) dx = I$.

Letting $u = g(x)$, $u' = g'(x)$, $v' = f'(x), v = f(x)$ in the integration by parts, we get:

$I = \left[g(0 +2)f(0 +2) - g(0)f(0) \right] - \int_{0}^{2} f(x)g'(x)dx = \int_{0}^{2} f(x) \left(- g'(x) \right)dx$.

It follows that $(D^{*}g)(x) = - g'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: recall the integration by parts formula:

$$
\int_a^bf^\prime(x) g(x)dx = f(x)g(x)\Big\vert_a^b - \int_a^bf(x)g^\prime(x) dx
$$

Comment: Alright, I used the formula, but I still don't see how $T^* = -T$. You still get one side of the equation with $f'$, and one with $g'$?

Comment: Write down the defining equation for $T^*$: you need $\langle Tf,g\rangle = \langle f,T^*g\rangle$.  Use this, your definition of $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$, and integration by parts.

Comment: For the LHS, I get $\int f g' $, but for the RHS I get $\int f' g?$ How are these equal?

Comment: @MathLogic They're not, there's a minus sign. And they *are* equal with the minus sign, that's what it means to be an adjoint.